# AS3 Vector remove display list

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an app which is using a vector object to create and display multiple dynamic items on the stage.

When I quit the game and then return to the inGame screen the objects are still visible. I have tried a number of ways to remove but nothing has worked.

I have null'ed the vectors but the objects still remain on the stage.

Basically I just need to clear the stage when the game is quit.

I am using:

```
var item = new Vector.<Item>();
```

to create.

The user quits the game by hitting the pause button and then a 'back to menu' button.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Also you could put more context as how you are performing "cleaning" before going to the inGame screen. Also what constituates the screen - maybe you have a single container that contains all items and you can do: `while(theContainer.numChildren) { theContainer.removeChildAt(0); }` but then why to use Vector list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you perform an `addChild()` on something, that something receives another link to it, namely from display list. So you have to manually call `removeChild()` on each of your dynamic objects you store in your Vector, before actually dropping the vector.

```
var item:Vector.<Item>;
for (var i:int=item.length-1;i>=0;i--) 
    item[i].parent.removeChild(item[i]);
item=null;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I am calling the removeChild outside of the function that created the item and the above gave and error 'Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.'

Comment: Okay, then you have to check if the object has a parent. If yes, then call `parent.removeChild()` otherwise skip.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. I should say I am new to Vectors in AS3

Comment: Count Vectors as Arrays, and do as you do with Arrays. `for (var i:int=item.length-1;i>=0;i--) if (item[i].parent) item[i].parent.removeChild(item[i]);`

Comment: Sorry, this did work. For some reason when recompiling it ignored this statement but after a reboot worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If all of your DisplayObject's are in the `item` Vector and Item is an ancestor of `DisplayObject` then following loop executed when you are going to the main screen will remove them from it's container.

```
var child:Item;
while(item.length)
{
    child = item.shift();
    if(child)
    {
        //perform some cleaning functionality e.g. child.destroy();//if there is destroy method for disposing Item class
        //
        if(child.parent)
        {
            child.parent.removeChild(child);
        }
        child = null;
    }
}
//
item = null;
```